# Verb compromise

Tags: verbs

Can I use the verb compromise in this sentence that means'ruin'?

A: Could you please edit my essay? 
B: I'm afraid I can't. I might *compromise* your essay

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One may use **compromise** as *harm*

> (verb) to risk having a harmful effect on [something](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/compromise) (CED)

In the context of the question, compromise is a good choice.

> I might *compromise* your essay

I do not think there is any reason not to use compromise, it may be as good a word choice as any.

The other principle use of **compromise** a a verb

> (verb) to allow your principles to be less strong or your standards or morals to be [lower](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/compromise) (CED)

does not conflict enough with your intent to cause any real issue.